# Get id of each task of a worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails

these are my models:

`worker.rb:`

```
class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

`task.rb:`

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :worker
  attr_accessible :done, :name
end
```

I have in: `views/workers/index.html.erb` a list of all of the workers, and near each of them: "show tasks". this link sends the user to: `views/tasks/index.html.erb`.

in `tasks_controller`, I have:

```
def index
    @task = Worker.where(:name => params[:worker_id])
    @worker_name = params[:worker_id]
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @worker }
    end
end
```

and this is my: `views/tasks/index.html.erb`:

```
<center>Task of <%= @worker_name %></center><br>
<table>
   <% @task.each do |task| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= task.name %></td>
        <td><%= task.task %></td>
        <td><%= task.done %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

I want to add `<td>` with the id of each task. something like:

```
<td><%= task.id %></td>
```

Comment: `@task = Worker.where(:name => params[:worker_id])` -> you are assigning a worker to a variable named `@task`, is this right? This sounds very weird to me.

Comment: @shioyama, maybe I didn't do it well. I want the tasks of the 'worker_id'..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1.9.3-p194 :043 > Worker.all.each do |worker|
1.9.3-p194 :044 >   puts "workerID: "+worker.id.to_s
1.9.3-p194 :045?>   worker.tasks.each do |task|
1.9.3-p194 :046 >     puts "taskID: "+task.id.to_s
1.9.3-p194 :047?>   end
1.9.3-p194 :048?> end
```

Controller: Add  `@workers = Worker.all`

View:

```
<table>
   <% @workers.each do |worker| %>
      <tr>
        <td>Worker:</td>
        <td><%= worker.id %></td>
        <td><%= worker.name %></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
     <% worker.tasks.all
       <tr>
          <td><%= task.id %></td>
          <td><%= task.name %></td>
          <td><%= task.task %></td>
          <td><%= task.done %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding this correctly, I think you want something like this:

#### controller.rb

```
@worker = Worker.find_by_name(params[:worker_id]) # might want to eager load tasks
@tasks  = @worker.tasks
# @worker_name = params[:worker_id] # don't need this anymore
...
```

#### view.html.erb

```
<center>Task of <%= @worker.name %></center>
<table>
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.id %></td>
    <td><%= task.name %></td>
...
```

Comment: thank you.. unfortunately, I got an error: NoMethodError in TasksController#index

undefined method `tasks' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb65a0918>
Rails.root: /home/alon/projects/TODO

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:5:in `index'
Request

Parameters:

{"worker_id"=>"alon"}

Comment: Ah, missed this. `where` returns a collection vs. a single object. Since you seem to be doing a search against `name` you can use this `find_by_<attribute>` method. If you were just looking up the id, you could just use `find`

Comment: thank you for your comment. now, the lines of the <table> print nothing :/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show id with each task you have many ways, 
  - you can take count variable in print it while iterating then loop
  - 2nd is you can user ruby method each_with_index as follow;

```
<center>Task of <%= @worker_name %></center><br>
<table>
   <% @task.each_with_index do |task, i| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= i %></td>
        <td><%= task.name %></td>
        <td><%= task.task %></td>
        <td><%= task.done %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

i hope it would answer your question

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. the tasks have an id. so this is not right that the id of the tasks are: 1,2,3... the id of the tasks of worker 'alon' can be: 4,6,8 (because the first task that was send to 'alon' is the forth task of the workers.. I hope you understand me.. thank you for trying!